# Dependencies between different solver runs with z3py

Tags: python, z3py

I am running a couple experiments with the Z3 solver (z3py API), where I measure the quality of the results depending on the timeout, that I set. I am running the different experiments from the same vitualenv but from different classes. After each Experiment i am creating a new solver object like this:

```
self.solver = z3.Solver()
```

I have the feeling that results are found faster in the second and so on runs. So I was wondering, whether the z3py API somehow saves some of the preliminary results from previous runs in order to speed up the next one. If so, is there a way to completely reset the solver after a run.

Comment: Related to this, I have noticed that satisfiable solutions are found in different times depending on previous experiments. Not always faster but consistent, i.e. the same order of experiments give approximately the same times to a solution. Since it's not always faster to have experiments solved before, the idea that things need to "warm up" seems to be ruled out. Did you manage to find out what the cause was for you? Why does there seem to be a dependency between solvers in the same python instance, even when they are different solver objects?

Answer (score 0):

This is extremely unlikely, especially given you're creating the solver anew from scratch. But it is impossible to opine on this as you haven't really shown any code to see if there might be gotchas.

I'd hazard a guess that if you always observe the first solution to be slower than the following ones, make sure you properly account for your Python interpreter to start up, load your program, load all the z3 infrastructure it needs and finally call the solver. Notice that none of that is going to be cheap, especially if the problems you are benchmarking are rather small.

A good way to go would be to toss away the timing results from the first couple of runs, to make sure all the cache-lines in the memory are warmed up and everything is paged in. Then do a comparison of the runs 3 to 15.. Do you still see a difference? That would suggest the presence of other factors, though I doubt it.

But again, it all depends on how you coded this up and what sort of problems you are benchmarking. The random seed chosen by the solver can play a role, but the impact of that should be randomly distributed, if any.